# Conversion to grams

Tags: c

Can someone please explain why the .exe program is not running despite the turbo c++ compiler not showing any error?

the compiler doesnt show any error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
int choice;
float num, result;
printf("Select your choice\n");
printf("Press 1 for conversion from milligrams to grams\n");
printf("Press 2 for conversion from decigrams to grams\n");
printf("Press 3 for conversion from centigrams to grams\n");
printf("Press 4 for conversion from kilograms to grams\n");
printf("Press 5 for conversion from ounce to grams\n");
printf("Press 6 for conversion from pounds to grams\n");
printf("Press 7 for conversion from ton to grams\n");

switch(choice) //i thought the switch statement would be appropriate
{
case 1:
        printf("Enter the weight in milligrams for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*0.001;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        getch();
        break;

case 2:
        printf("Enter the weight in decigrams for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*0.1;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        getch();
        break;

case 3:
        printf("Enter the weight in centigrams for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*0.01;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        getch();
        break;

case 4:
        printf("Enter the weight in kilograms for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*1000.0;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        getch();
        break;

case 5:
        printf("Enter the weight in ounce for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*28.3495;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        getch();
        break;

case 6:
        printf("Enter the weight in pounds for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*453.592;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        getch();
        break;

case 7:
        printf("Enter the weight in ton for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*907185.00;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        getch();
        break;

default:
        printf("invalid choice\n");
        break;
        }
        return 0;
        }
```

i am relatively new to c to i dont know what is my mistake

Comment: How do you mean, "not running"? What output do you get?

Comment: the compiler is only looking for obvious mistakes. You can still have a lot of errors in a program which compiles fine. Anyway, turn on warnings and you'll see that you never set `choice`. How does it know what choice the user made?

Comment: It seems that scanf has invalid input format. Shouldn't it `scanf("%f", &num)` ?

Comment: &#37; is the html representation of the %-sign. may be a copy&paste error from a web page? however, it's an error

Comment: yes i did remove the getch() that was appearing twice and i did remove the &#37f

Answer (score 5):

Your variable `choice` is uninitialized and never written to. After prompting the user for input, you need to actually scan for the entered value.

Comment: yes that was the mistake, thank you now my program is running and the compiler gave me the accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use scanf before the switch.
It doesn't work because you did not assign any value to 'choice'. 
use only one scanf and use it before switch.

Answer (score 1):

Get the input for the user choice first before checking it in switch statement. Hope this helps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
int choice;
float num, result;
printf("Select your choice\n");
printf("Press 1 for conversion from milligrams to grams\n");
printf("Press 2 for conversion from decigrams to grams\n");
printf("Press 3 for conversion from centigrams to grams\n");
printf("Press 4 for conversion from kilograms to grams\n");
printf("Press 5 for conversion from ounce to grams\n");
printf("Press 6 for conversion from pounds to grams\n");
printf("Press 7 for conversion from ton to grams\n");

scanf("%d",&choice);        //Added this line

switch(choice) //i thought the switch statement would be appropriate
{
case 1:
        printf("Enter the weight in milligrams for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*0.001;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        break;

case 2:
        printf("Enter the weight in decigrams for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*0.1;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        break;

case 3:
        printf("Enter the weight in centigrams for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*0.01;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        break;

case 4:
        printf("Enter the weight in kilograms for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*1000.0;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        break;

case 5:
        printf("Enter the weight in ounce for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*28.3495;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        break;

case 6:
        printf("Enter the weight in pounds for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*453.592;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        break;

case 7:
        printf("Enter the weight in ton for conversion\n");
        scanf("&#37;f", &num);

        result=num*907185.00;

        printf("The weight in after conversion is %f g", result);
        getch();
        break;

default:
        printf("invalid choice\n");
        break;
       }
        return 0;
  }
```

Plus I didn't understand the used format specifier `scanf("&#37;f", &num);` in your case, I have used `scanf("%f",&num);`